# Can't Change Button's Image after Success Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with image input type:

```
<form data-ajax="false" method="post" name="login_form" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="image" src ="images/internetimyok.png" class="img-responsive center-block" name="submit" value="Invite" class="submitBtn" id="resim"></input>
   </div>
</form>
```

What it does, when user simply clicks it, it sends a notification email to me. Here is the jQuery part where it handles the send email and change image;

```
$('form').bind('submit', function() {

    var ret = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/mailgonder.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data, status, xhttp) {
            // data will be true or false if you returned a json bool
            ret = data;
            alert('Gonderildi');
            // change image after success call (DOESN'T WORK)
            $('#input').attr("src", "newURL");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Mail gönderilemedi, lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyin.\nMail could not be sent, please try again later.');
        },
        async: false // this is generally bad, it will lock up your browser while it returns, but the only way to fit it into your pattern.

    });
    return ret;
})
```

When I try to use `$('#input').attr("src", "newURL");` on `onClick()` event just to test, it works. But I couldn't make it work on jQuery.

*Side note: It reloads the form and changes image to default when I try it on `onClick()`*

Is there any simple method I could change the image after a success call?

Comment: The id in your seelctor is wrong, and as per your comment you should really, *really* remove the `async: false`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am having issues with Firefox when I remove it

Comment: Ajax has nothing to do with this problem and can't change button images at all.

Comment: @Rob It does change, but it reloads back to the original one after a few milisecond.

Comment: Ajax has nothing to do with changing button images

Comment: @Rob It just worked, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. Your image input's `id` is `resim`, not `input`:

   ```
   <input type="image" ... id="resim">
   <!-- -------------------^^^^^^^^^^ -->
   ```

   So:

   ```
   $('#resim').attr("src", "newURL");
   ```
2. You're setting `ret` to `data`, which will be a **string** since that's what you've told it to be (`dataType: 'text'`). So if the ajax call works, you'll never return `false`, you'll return some string; and the form submission will go forward because you haven't cancelled it. Since you're submitting a form, the page is torn down and replaced with a freshly-loaded version from the server — which will, of course, have the original `src` for the image input.

If you want the form submission to be prevented, return `false`, not a string. If you want a different `src` on the image after submitting the form, do that server-side.

---

Side note: `</input>` is never valid. `input` elements are void elements, so in HTML they're simply written `<input ...>` (although `<input .../>` is tolerated). In XHTML, they're `<input.../>`. But never `<input></input>`.

Side note 2: I don't see any point to having the form submission wait until you do a POST to your server, and then once that POST is complete, submit the form...to your server. Just have your server do both pieces of work on form submission (not doing the second thing if the first thing doesn't work, if that's what you want to happen). Using a synchronous ajax request is horrible UX, to be avoided if at all possible.

---

As long as you're not trying to submit the form to a different window, you can avoid using `async: false` by cancelling the user's form submission, doing your email ajax call, and then programmatically submitting the form when it completes, see the `***` and `TODO` comments:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function() {

    // TODO: Probably worth disabling the submit button here...

    var form = this; // Use `this`, NOT `$(this)`!
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/mailgonder.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data, status, xhttp) {
            // change image after success call
            $('#resim').attr("src", "newURL");

            // *** Submit the form - because you're calling it directly on the DOM
            // element, it won't re-trigger the submit handler
            form.submit();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Mail gönderilemedi, lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyin.\nMail could not be sent, please try again later.');

            // TODO: If you disabled the submit button earlier, enable it again
        }
        // *** Yay, no `async: false` anymore
    });

    // *** Always cancel user's form submission, we'll do it for them above
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for pointing out those problems. I have fixed them. Everything is perfectly working after fixing `ret` to return boolean instead of string.

Comment: Good deal, glad that helped.

Comment: @MesutK: Just FWIW, I added an alternative to the end of the answer that doesn't require `async: false`

Comment: @T-J-Crowder Thank you for great explanation, I really do appreciate. People like you encourage us ("the newbs")  to learn much more :-)